# Just a little Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

A one word riddle

About a group of people

Starts with an animal

Ends with an animal

And Metals in the Middle

A one word Riddle

Comment: Is the change of capitalization of "Riddle" a part of the puzzle?

Comment: No. It is not. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest:

> battalion
>  
>  bat ta lion

> There can be 3 Metals in the middle. Ta, Al and Li

Comment: Li is lithium which is a metal too, maybe they can overlap

Comment: You missed to count another metal in there too.

Comment: Note also the astatine in there, but its a metalloid/halogen, not a metal